# Display filename readline with switch case android

Tags: android, text, switch-statement, filenames, readline

I want to know why this section of my coding is not working, and the program keep giving me the same error at the switch;

(Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted)

I want to read the file that I saved as a txt file and display it on the program.

Eg: I wrote there "Email" as a case, so I wrote what I want and save it into a txt file to be read in this switch.

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
        private void ExecuteCommands(String filename) {
     //Find the directory for the SD Card using the API
    //*Don't* hardcode "/sdcard"
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    //Get the text file
    File file = new File(sdcard, filename + ".txt");

    //Read text from file
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] tmp = line.split(" ");

                        //this switch case giving me problem
                      switch(tmp[0]){

             case "Email":
                String subject = sbj.getText().toString();
                String message = messageBody.getText().toString();
                String to = destinationAddress.getText().toString();

                Intent emailActivity = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                //set up the recipient address
                emailActivity.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { to });

                //set up the email subject
                emailActivity.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

                //you can specify cc addresses as well
                // email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ ...});
                // email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{ ... });

                //set up the message body
                emailActivity.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

                emailActivity.setType("message/rfc822");

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailActivity, "Select your Email Provider :"));
                break;

            case "SMS message":
             String phoneNo = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();
              String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();

              try {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();


                break;
              }
            }
        }


    }



        catch (IOException e) {
        //You'll need to add proper error handling here
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

How you can't have switch/case on string  in `Java` version  under 7, Consider use enum, but how  your switch case string can contains white space you can't retrieve the enum constants throught `valutOf` enum methods, but you can add own method to retrieve the counterpart enum based on specific string. like this.

```
enum Type {

EMAIL {
    @Override
    public boolean counterpart(String value) {
        if (value.equals(EMAIL)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
},
SMS {
    @Override
    public boolean counterpart(String value) {
        if (value.equals(SMS_TAG)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
private static final String EMAIL_TAG = "Email";
private static final String SMS_TAG = "SMS Message";

public abstract boolean counterpart(String value);
```

}

and a public static method anywhere that return the corresponded type based on string value.

```
 public static Type  getType( String value ) {
    for (Type t : Type.values()) {
        if (t.counterpart(value )) {
            return t;
        }
    }
    return Type.EMAIL;
}
```

Then you should have a swicth like this

```
    Type type = getType( param[ 0 ] );

    switch( type ){
        case EMAIL:
            break;
        case SMS:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```